# Can a graph have multiple distinct minimum spanning trees?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization

I have the following undirected graph which has multiple edges that have the same edge weights, the question is it possible to find more than one distinct minimum spanning tree for the following graph?

[image: Undirected graph]

Comment: Sure, the four edges of weight $1$ and $2$ and either edge of weight $3$ gives two minimal spanning trees.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: yes, the 3-cycle, with all its edges having weight 1, has three distinct minimum spanning trees, all of weight 2.

Comment: The only time a spanning tree is unique is when the graph itself is a tree. Any cycle allows you to find distinct spanning trees.

Comment: @CyclotomicField If the weights are distinct, the minimum spanning tree is unique whether or not the graph is a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for this graph you can construct two MST with the same weight 9 (they differ in the last edge):

- (B-C), (C-D), (D-E), (E-F), (A-F);
- (B-C), (C-D), (D-E), (E-F), (A-B).